# Rebinding copy & paste in urxvt

Tags: rxvt

rxvt-unicode has the ability to copy to/from system clipboard using `Ctrl+Meta+C` and `Ctrl+Meta+V` (`Meta` is `Alt` usually).

Is there a way to rebind those functions to other keys? `Ctrl+Shift+C` and `Ctrk+Shift+V` would be more intuitive choice.

Answer (score 7):

I just managed to get this working yesterday. Here are the X resources I needed:

```
! Disable ISO 14755 unicode input so we can use Ctrl-Shift bindings
URxvt.iso14755:        false
URxvt.iso14755_52:     false

! Disable Ctrl-Alt-c & Ctrl-Alt-v bindings (optional)
URxvt.keysym.C-M-c:    builtin-string:
URxvt.keysym.C-M-v:    builtin-string:

! Bind Ctrl-Shift-c & Ctrl-Shift-v to copy and paste
! I dont know why, but I needed to use hex keysym values to get it to work
URxvt.keysym.C-S-0x43: eval:selection_to_clipboard
URxvt.keysym.C-S-0x56: eval:paste_clipboard
```

Comment: What about Ctrl+C / Ctrl+V ? :) Looks like it doesn't work in the same way

Answer (score 1):

Changing the last two lines as follows changes ctrl-shift-c/v to ctrl-c/v.
Change:

```
URxvt.keysym.C-S-0x43: eval:selection_to_clipboard
URxvt.keysym.C-S-0x56: eval:paste_clipboard
```

To:

```
URxvt.keysym.C-0x63: eval:selection_to_clipboard
URxvt.keysym.C-0x76: eval:paste_clipboard
```

Comment: Great answer. Now I wonder how do I make it so the ctrl+c still terminates the process in the terminal and gives you a new prompt. That doesn't work anymore